# Каковы истоки гениальности? — таков главный вопрос

Tags: пунктуация

Не могли бы подсказать, как оформляется данный вопрос? При условии, что это не является никаким цитированием и тп. Как вообще в данных случаях оформляется предложение и на основании какого правила?

**Каковы истоки гениальности? — таков главный вопрос...**

Заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В таких случаях я предпочитаю ориентироваться на правило *разрешено то, что не запрещено* при условии многократных прецедентов в хороших издательствах. В гугло-книгах несложно найти самые различные варианты оформления: со знаком вопроса и без, с кавычками в первой части, с разделением предложений и т. п. Приведу только несколько (из огромного количества) примеров такого оформления, какое предложено в вопросе:

> Кто виноват в несчастии этих людей? — вот главный вопрос... ("Герцен —
> литературный критик", Просвещение, 1967)
>
> Как делать его сценическую жизнь временной? — вот главный вопрос,
> который поднял... ("В творческой лаборатории Чехова", Наука, 1974)
>
> Как себя чувствуете, Юрий? — вот главный вопрос... ("Земля и
> Вселенная", Наука, 1971)
>
> Счастлив ли народ? — вот главный вопрос, волновавший поэта всю жизнь.
> ("Вопросы преподавания ...", сборник, Просвещение, 1981)
>
> Во что? — вот главный вопрос, ответ на который должно дать такое
> исследование. ("Коммунист", Правда, 1985)

Comment: *разрешено то, что не запрещено* — никогда не видел в правилах слов  "нельзя" и "запрещено".

Comment: @oleedd Посмотрите для расширения кругозора [правила переноса](http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/rules/141-perenos), например. В справочниках Розенталя, "Грамматике" Шведовой и в др. источниках Вы, вероятно, не раз встречали выражения *не употребляется, не ставится* и т. п., просто не осознавали, что таким образом оформляется запрет на употребление, постановку и т. п.

Comment: Имел в виду правила пунктуации. Ведь знак вопроса — по части пунктуации.

Comment: @oleedd И что?! Вы уверены, что дочитали мой предыдущий комментарий до конца? Вы никогда не встречали в правилах выражения *не ставится [такой-то знак препинания в таких-то условиях]*? Или Вы не поняли моё объяснение, что это означает запрет? Выражайтесь, пожалуйста, точнее, если Вам есть что сказать, или просто согласитесь со мной, если уже смогли понять мою мысль. Я не хотел бы ставить здесь рекорды по количеству комментариев, переливая опять с пустого в порожнее.

Comment: Хочу сказать, что в правилах не указаны все возможные ошибки. Там в основном наоборот: указано, когда надо ставить. Это вам не кодекс о правонарушениях.

Comment: Теперь Вы говорите какие-то банальности (а выше Вы говорили что-то совсем другое). Ну ладно. Прочитайте, пожалуйста, ещё раз первое предложение моего ответа повнимательнее. У меня складывается уверенное впечатление, что Вы его не поняли или не дочитали до конца. Конечно, я нигде не утверждаю, что "это вам кодекс о правонарушениях".

Comment: В этой теме у Розенталя лишь 7 пунктов — о том, когда вопросительный знак ставится. Нет ни одного пункта о запрете. Там не указано, что вопросительный знак не ставится в начале предложения. Получается, что его можно ставить в начале предложения. Очень удобный у вас принцип. Его можно под много чего абсурдного подогнать.

Comment: Всё. Увольте. Такого уровня троллинг мне неинтересен.

Answer (score 1):

Не разрешается в правилах использовать знак вопроса в середине сложного предложения.

В середине предложения разрешается только такое:
Вопросительный знак может ставиться в вопросительном предложении после каждого однородного члена с целью расчленения вопроса:
*Что я — попугай? индейка?

Кравцов ласково улыбался — его нетерпению? самомнению? гениальности?*
И то это больше как отклонение от нормы.

Пусть бы и разрешалось — оно здесь всё равно не подходит.
Если спрашиваете непосредственно, то надо так:
*Каковы истоки гениальности? Таков главный вопрос...* || Две разных мысли. Сначала задаём глубокий вопрос, а потом говорим про него.
Наверно, всё-таки там не спрашивается, а просто приводится вопрос. Тогда нужны кавычки:
"Каковы истоки гениальности?" — таков главный вопрос... || Даётся текст, а потом говорится, что это. Если на самом деле не спрашиваете, то нельзя без кавычек. Знак вопроса подразумевает прямой вопрос — к читающему. Кавычки же его блокируют.
Похожий пример:
*"Каковы истоки гениальности?" — это наш главный вопрос.* || Никто ничего не спрашивает.

Но можно придумать предложение, где знак вопроса будет в середине:
*Сколько это стоит? — хочу тебя спросить.*
Так нельзя. В таком случае необходимо поменять местами:
*Хочу тебя спросить, сколько это стоит?*

Comment: Кем не разрешается и главное - почему ? :> Единственный адекватный критерий тут может быть - семантическая непонятность, но я такого не вижу :>  
"Так нельзя. Так нельзя. " - Да моооожно(с)

Comment: "Знак вопроса подразумевает прямой вопрос — к читающему. Кавычки же его блокируют. "Каковы истоки гениальности?" — это наш главный вопрос. || Никто ничего не спрашивает." - как я понимаю, разбираемый вопрос не блокируется - но единственно по причине того, что он риторический де-факто и никакой "читающий" ответить на него не в состоянии. Нуууууууу, а если вдруг и внезапно - в состоянии, то исполать ему :>>>>

Comment: Нет, он не риторический. Раз говорится, что он главный, то на него требуется ответ. Из Википедии: По сути, риторический вопрос — это вопрос, ответ на который не требуется или не ожидается в силу его крайней очевидности. Он не очевидный, а философский и сложный.

Comment: Он главный - но риторический :> Как я выше сказал - никто не в состоянии дать на него научный (то есть единственно значимый) ответ. Де-факто. Мне такие не известны, во всяком случае. А вам ? - и это тоже вопрос риторический. 
В общем, см. выше, и всё тут.

Comment: Протестую. А никто не просит научный ответ, любой сойдёт. В риторических вопросах другое: привлечь внимание, призыв к действию.

Comment: ну если это словоблудие ни о чем, то и говорить не о чем.  
Хотя с чего вы взяли что "никто не просит" - это неизвестно :>

"В риторических вопросах другое: ...призыв к действию. " - ерунда. "в силу его крайней очевидности. " - и это тоже не обязательно. Точнее очевидность тут в том - что ответ никому не известен :>
"Привлечь внимание" - что и происходит.

Comment: Да ладно, даже мне известен, можно поразмышлять и сказать, откуда берётся гениальность. Виды риторических вопросов: https://ktonanovenkogo.ru/voprosy-i-otvety/ritoricheskij-vopros-chto-ehto-takoe-primery.html

Comment: oleedd,  ясен перец  - из бутылки. 

Является ли Земля плоской ? - ответ на этот важный вопрос известен всем, кроме секты сумасшедших плоскоземельщиков. 
Вот вам риторический вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Это предложение с бессоюзно-изъяснительной связью. Если условно-главное предложение расположено перед условно-придаточным и содержит слова ‟так”, ‟таков”, ‟такой”, ‟одно” то между предложениями ставится двоеточие. Вот [ссылка (пункт 2)](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=150#pp150) на Розенталя и вот предложение из этой главы:

> Как все московские, ваш батюшка таков: желал бы зятя он с звездами и чинами (Гр).

Если условно-главное предложение расположено после условно-придаточного и содержит слова ‟так”, ‟таков”, ‟такой”, ‟одно” то между предложениями ставится двоеточие. [Ссылка (пункт 8)](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=151#pp151), предложение:

> Идти вперёд или погибнуть — таков был выбор у партизанского отряда.

Что касается вопросительного знака, то его вообще нигде не следует ставить, и это всех устроит. Ведь действительно, в середине составных предложений вопросительные знаки никогда не ставятся. Просто напишите так:

> **Каковы истоки гениальности — таков главный вопрос...**

Я думаю, что такое решение будет наилучшим.

Кто-то может сказать, что это предложение с сложноподчиненно-изъяснительной связью, а не бессоюзной, но нет. Если в главном или условно-главном есть слово, которое обозначает что-то, а это что-то, обозначенное каким-либо словом, раскрывается в последующем предложении, то это бессоюзная связь, даже если последующее предложение начинается со слов ‟что”, ‟кто”, ‟каков” и т.п. Для примера, предложение: ‟Он задал вопрос: сколько времени?” — с бессоюзной связью, а предложение: ‟Он спросил, сколько времени” — с сложноподчиненной связью.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131827/discussion-on-answer-by-jim-korbett------).